# convert large list to json string

Tags: java, json, list, bigdata

I have a list containing 9864284 elements and I want to convert this list to a json string, I used a recursive method, but I have always outOfMemory exception.

```
public String createRecuJson(List<CustomObject> inputList, int nElement, int index, List<String> result, String resJson) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if( index + nElement > inputList.size() ) {
        resJson = resJson.concat(","+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputList.subList(index,inputList.size())).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        result.add(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputList.subList(index,inputList.size())));
        return resJson;
    }else {
        final List<CustomObject> subListCustomObjects = inputList.subList(index, index+nElement);
        if(resJson.length() == 0)
            resJson.concat(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(subListCustomObjects).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        else
            resJson = resJson.concat(","+objectMapper.writeValueAsString(subListCustomObjects).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
        result.add(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(subListCustomObjects));
        return createRecuJson(inputList, nElement, index+nElement, result, resJson);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use Apache Spark for such large datasets. Even if I'm only running it on a laptop. Spark has support for JSON and JSON lines.

Comment: @steven35 can you share an example (url for example) I never use apache spark

Comment: You can try to use StringBuilder instead of String resJson and then return resJson.toString(). Does it make sense to have both resJson and result?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you create the JSON yourself? Usually, you would use something like JSON-B to achieve the task (https://javaee.github.io/jsonb-spec/getting-started.html)

Comment: @maio290 I use jackson to achieve the task but I have an outOfMemory

Comment: When I was a student, we dealt with rather outdated slow machines with lack of RAM. Is it an option to dump the JSON into a file with many lines (one array item per line) and then send it if needed say via HTTP line after line? You will need to compose your own json serialization, I believe

Comment: And when does this error appear? I mean, 9864284 elements are quit a lot to handle, thus it's pretty easy to go out of memory.  How much memory did you allocate to your JVM? A stupid approach would be to split the serialization to a determined amount of elements and writing the json onto the disk.

Comment: @maio290 I use 4Go of memory for my JVM, I want to serialize this list in order to save the totality of json string into db

Comment: 4 GB seems a bit limited for this job, when you're doing it with libraries, not dedicated to big data sets. Probably, this isn't even enough to hold the whole JSON in memory...

Comment: The standard way of solving this is to use the streaming capabilities of your serializing library in order to avoid keeping the whole data in memory. [Here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonStreamingApi#creating-generators)'s the relevant doc for Jackson. That means reworking your API though as you won't have a String containing the whole JSON as any point.

Comment: When you call a recursive function, the called function and the caller function will be still in memory. It seems your data does not fit into memory. Maybe you try writing to a file?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Jackson Streaming API` instead of your implementation. It is the lowest level of write access to JSON content.

[Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator) you can find some examples.